# How to access macOS NSApp popover property

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I have a popover initialised in my macOS app's Main lifecycle file:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate{

var statusItem: NSStatusItem?
var popOver = NSPopover()
var authentication = Authentication()

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    
    let menuView = MenuView().environmentObject(authentication)
    
    popOver.behavior = .transient
    popOver.animates = true
    popOver.contentViewController = NSViewController()
    popOver.contentViewController?.view = NSHostingView(rootView: menuView)
    
    popOver.contentViewController?.view.window?.makeKey()
    
    statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    
    
    if let MenuButton = statusItem?.button{
        
        //            MenuButton.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "arrow.up.doc", accessibilityDescription: nil)
        MenuButton.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("icon_2"))
        //                        MenuButton.image?.isTemplate = true
        
        
        MenuButton.action = #selector(MenuButtonToggle)
        
    }
    
    if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first {
        window.close()
    }
}

@objc func MenuButtonToggle(sender: AnyObject? = nil){
    
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL
    
    if popOver.isShown{
        popOver.performClose(sender)
    }
    else{
        if let menuButton = statusItem?.button{
            NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
            self.popOver.show(relativeTo: menuButton.bounds, of: menuButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
        }
    }
}

@objc func closePopover(_ sender: AnyObject? = nil) {
    popOver.performClose(sender)
}

@objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject? = nil) {
    if popOver.isShown {
        closePopover(sender)
    } else {
        MenuButtonToggle(sender: sender)
    }
}
}
```

I was just wondering how I'd access the `popOver` property outside my AppDelegate, more specifically in the rest of my SwiftUI code. I need to be able to close the `popOver` after something happens, e.g:

```
checkFile(localURL: url, completion: { res, error in
    // Close popover
    // I assume it'll be something like NSApplication.shared.....
})
```

My full applications lifecycle is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Preferences
import Purchases

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate


var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        MenuView()
            .environmentObject(self.delegate.authentication)
    }
    WindowGroup("Login") {
        LoginView()
            .environmentObject(self.delegate.authentication)
    }.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "LoginView"))
    Settings{
        SettingsView()
            .environmentObject(self.delegate.authentication)
    }
    WindowGroup("Settings") {
        SettingsView()
            .environmentObject(self.delegate.authentication)
    }.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "SettingsView"))
}
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate{

var statusItem: NSStatusItem?
var popOver = NSPopover()
var authentication = Authentication()

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    
    let menuView = MenuView().environmentObject(authentication)
    
    popOver.behavior = .transient
    popOver.animates = true
    popOver.contentViewController = NSViewController()
    popOver.contentViewController?.view = NSHostingView(rootView: menuView)
    
    popOver.contentViewController?.view.window?.makeKey()
    
    statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    
    
    if let MenuButton = statusItem?.button{
        
        //            MenuButton.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "arrow.up.doc", accessibilityDescription: nil)
        MenuButton.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("icon_2"))
        //                        MenuButton.image?.isTemplate = true
        
        
        MenuButton.action = #selector(MenuButtonToggle)
        
    }
    
    if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first {
        window.close()
    }
}

@objc func MenuButtonToggle(sender: AnyObject? = nil){
    
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL
    
    if popOver.isShown{
        popOver.performClose(sender)
    }
    else{
        if let menuButton = statusItem?.button{
            NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
            self.popOver.show(relativeTo: menuButton.bounds, of: menuButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
        }
    }
}

@objc func closePopover(_ sender: AnyObject? = nil) {
    popOver.performClose(sender)
}

@objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject? = nil) {
    if popOver.isShown {
        closePopover(sender)
    } else {
        MenuButtonToggle(sender: sender)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the application instance using `NSApplication.shared` or `NSApp` (both of which refer to the app instance, and both of which are documented on the page for NSApplication). Once you have that, you can get the delegate, e.g.:

```
let delegate = NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

(It seems safe to force-convert the delegate since you presumably know a) that the app delegate exists, and b) what it's type is.)

Once you have the delegate, just use it to get the popover:

```
let popover = delegate.popover
```

Comment: I get a `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when initialising `let delegate = NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate` in my code? (The app delegate does exist)

Comment: I have added my full app's lifecycle file